# Multiple minimum index of a list without using numpy

Tags: python

Is there a faster way to implement this function?

```
def minIndex(array):
    minarray = min(array)
    min_index = []
    for item in range(len(array)):
        if array[item] == minarray:
            min_index.append(item)
    return min_index

array = [0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, -2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, -2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -2] 
minIndex(array)
[6, 12, 21]
```

Comment: It depends on how fast you type and how much you know python.  Any compressed one-liner may take weeks to understand how to write.  It may also execute in the same time.

Comment: Using enumerate isn't any faster than the function minIndex(array) I wrote above. I am looking for a more efficient way of doing this.